# gcloud is stuck when trying to ssh to the virtual machine

Tags: google-app-engine, ssh

I am running this from the Terminal. Up until yesterday, it worked.

```
 gcloud compute --project my_project ssh --zone us-central1-a server_name
```

no it's stuck with *NO ERROR* message for hours.
I have installed `docker` and `boot2docker` yesterday and it's possibly connected to that. I tried uninstalling `docker` but still no luck.

Comment: I've reported the same issue. https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11845&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log

Comment: @DmitrySadovnychyi please upvote so that this question will get more views.

Comment: I don't think that this is the right question for SO.

Comment: It's not clear that the issue linked is the same as the code.google.com link, so I think that's unnecessarily confusing. All we can see from this moment is that there's latency in gcloud on the one hand, and latency in the devserver on the other... these could be quite different issues

Comment: OP, could you attempt to run `gcloud --verbosity debug compute --project my_project ssh --zone us-central1-a server_name` and share the results by editing your question?

Comment: the issue is now (since today) resolved

Comment: @OhadPerry how you resolve this? it happen to me